# Warning when move project files and directories to subdirectory and keep history

Tags: git

I have a git repository and want to move all files and directories to directory one level
bellow current directory and keep history of commits. I'm executing following commands:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "mkdir -p carDealership;mv carDealership /tmp;mv * /tmp/carDealership;mv /tmp/carDealership ./" HEAD
```

And get following warning. Is there a reason to worry about this warning?

```
Rewrite b56d2881a63a1803f3f65d630a8f47461809720e (1/17)mv: cannot stat ‘*’: No such file or directory
Rewrite b0c533ac2658e197cb97243cc4a61d7b553add07 (17/17)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

There is other solution. When I execute following commands line by line
and commit git detects that files is renamed and there is rename messages in history. 
What is the better way?

```
mkdir -p carDealership
mv carDealership /tmp
mv * /tmp/carDealership
mv /tmp/carDealership ./
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using `filter-branch` instead of simply using `git mv`?

Comment: I want to keep history same, but for the new subdirectory path.

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: "What is the better way?" You haven't explained why Git's rename detection is a problem for you. What are you looking for that rename detection doesn't provide?

Comment: It turns out that I do not need to use filter-branch. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `git mv`. Just make sure you don't put anything else in the move commit, to make it easier for git to detect the renames. Git rename detection is IMPLICIT. If you remove a file and add it under a different name, `git status` will tell you it was renamed.

You can see file histories across renames with

```
git log --follow <file>
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to all who wrote in the topic.